# How do I multiply $2(\frac{4}{y})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I multiply $2(\frac{4}{y})$? I'm having abit of trouble understanding how the answer is 8y...

Comment: The answer is actually $\frac{8}{y}$.

Comment: Think of it like this: $$2\left(\frac{4}{y}\right) = \frac{2}{1}\times\frac{4}{y}.$$ Then simply multiply the numerators and denominators together: $$\frac{2\times 4}{1\times y} = \frac{8}{y}.$$

Comment: Here's another example: $$2.5\left(\frac{x}{3}\right).$$ We can recognize $2.5$ as being nothing more than $\dfrac{5}{2}$ so that our expression is $$\frac{5}{2}\times\frac{x}{3}.$$ Again, if we multiply the numerators and denominators we get $$\frac{5\times x}{2\times 3} = \frac{5x}{6}$$ which can't be reduced any further.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Much thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

$2\frac{4}{y}=\frac{2\cdot 4}{y}=\frac{8}{y}$

Comment: Hey thanks for that, can you also show me how to solve for y in $\frac{8}{y} - y = 7$ ?

Comment: @TheAsker:  multiply by $y$ and you have a quadratic.  You can factor it or use the quadratic equation.